# "#define __SIZE_T" and "typedef unsigned int size_t"

Tags: c

I've come across the following declaration of "size_t" a few times now, but don't really know what this means:

```
#ifndef __SIZE_T
#define __SIZE_T
typedef unsigned int size_t;
#endif
```

What exactly is going on here? What is #define __SIZE_T doing? Isn't the typedef alone enough to get the job done?

Comment: this is probably because it relates to the size of objects, which could be machine specific (example an size_t(int) is different for x64 and x86)

Comment: It is a `if` statement for the preprocessor. `#ifndef __SIZE_T` says if not defined `__SIZE_T` then you will `#define __SIZE_T` and for it you provide a `typedef unsigned int size_t;` So in your code if a normal `__SIZE_T` was not defined, you get `unsigned int` typedeffed to `size_t` It is also shorthand that makes it more cryptic, longhand would be `#if not defined (__SIZE_T)` then the rest is readable.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin So if __SIZE_T were already defined, would you use the "size_t" type as 
`size_t a;` or `__SIZE_T a;`? Thanks!

Comment: If `__SIZE_T` were already defined, none of the rest would apply.

Answer (score 1):

Identifiers and macros with double underscore or one underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the compiler. So `__SIZE_T` is most likely something internal in the specific compiler. (I think for example gcc/glibc internally uses something called `__SIZE_TYPE__`.)

The `#ifndef ... #define` is simply conditional compilation (sometimes called sloppily called "compiler switch", which is also a term used for compiler arguments). It checks if  `__SIZE_T` has already been defined or not. This has to be a separate macro, since you can't do pre-processor checks on types. Something like `#ifndef size_t` won't work if `size_t` is a type.

So this seems to be a compiler's internal definition of the standard type `size_t` for a given compiler and target. Not something the application programmer need to care or worry about.

Typically you would find `size_t` inside `stddef.h`, same thing goes with `NULL`. However, the standard (7.19 and 7.21) states that `stdio.h` should also define these two. Hence the need for the macro, in case both `stddef.h` and `stdio.h` are included in the same program.

Comment: The reason for that is that `size_t` is defined by multiple standard headers. The idea here is that testing and defining `__SIZE_T` (or some other implementation-defined macro) avoids redefinition warnings when you include e.g. both `<string.h>` and `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: As for the "include `<stddef.h>` multiple times" trick you are hinting at, C forbids standard headers to include each other unless specifically specified (`<inttypes.h>` including `<stdint.h>`, for example). So the standard library cannot just defer `size_t` definition to `<stddef.h>`.

Comment: @DevSolar I'm pretty sure I've seen implementations include stddef.h from other library headers. Which would be the sensible thing to do.

Comment: @DevSolar Where does it say that library headers can't include each other? I can't find anything about it in chapter 7.

Comment: I think it was made explicit at some point, but that might have been an earlier revision, or Plaugher's commentary on it in "The Standard C Library". In any case, it follows from 7.1.3 Reserved Identifiers. The identifiers defined by each header's subclause are reserved if *and only if* "any of its associated headers is included", as "no other identifiers are reserved". That means that a user may e.g. use `max_align_t` in his program *unless* it explicitly includes `<stddef.h>`. If e.g. your `<stdio.h>` included `<stddef.h>` for its definition of `size_t`, that user's program would break.

Comment: @DevSolar I think I found the reason, it is rather in 7.21 regarding stdio.h specifically, where it says that the header should explicitly define `size_t` and `NULL`. So these two are a special oddball case defined in multiple headers. Answer updated.

Comment: `size_t` is defined by `<stddef.h>`, `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<string.h>`, `<time.h>`, `<uchar.h>`, and `<wchar.h>`... (Will look up the -- potential -- Plaugher reference as soon as I'm home and get my hands on my bookshelf.)

Comment: Just checked my copy of Plaugher's. In *Chapter 0: Introduction*, section *Using the Library*: "The headers have several properties: [...] They are *mutually independent*. [...] Nor does any standard header include another standard header." He then goes on (in the section *Implementing the Library*) to show *exactly* that snippet from OP's question (only with one leading underscore instead of two). ;-)